# App Language and Android Market Filtering

Tags: android, google-play

Does the Android Market/Google Play do some type of filtering based on the "Language" field selected in the Listing details?

My application (with English language) would not show when searched from a UK phone set up with Polish language. However, when I changed the language of the phone to English, the application then appeared in the market as normal.

Although I don't provide translations for the content of the app, I would still like my application to be browsable in the market for other countries other than US and UK...

Could someone shed some light please?